# When does $\exists x \forall y \phi(x,y) \leftrightarrow \forall y \exists x \phi(x,y)$ hold?

Tags: logic, axioms

Clearly, $\exists x \forall y \phi(x,y) \to \forall y \exists x \phi(x,y)$ is a tautology. However, the other way around is not a tautology: $\forall y \exists x \phi(x,y) \to \exists x \forall y \phi(x,y)$.

Nevertheless, I am interested in the case that this holds. That is, I am interested in the set of structures and formulae $\phi(x,y)$ where the following holds:

$$\exists x \forall y \phi(x,y) \leftrightarrow \forall y \exists x \phi(x,y)$$

Does there exist an analysis of structures where this statement holds? Are there interesting things to be said about them?

**EDIT:** Note that this does not require the statement to hold for arbitrary $\phi(x,y)$. i.e. if we need to restrict $\phi(x,y)$ in some way to get something interesting, then I still like to know about it.

Comment: A note on terminology: You use "is a tautology" to mean "is valid."  Many authors make a distinction and reserve "tautology" for those sentences that are obtained by substitution from propositional tautologies.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Hint 1:** It holds when the domain of discourse is a single object.

**Hint 2:**  It does not hold when the domain of discourse is empty.

---

**EDIT:** $\forall x \exists y \phi(x,y) \to \exists y \forall x \phi(x,y)$ will hold if and only if:

> $\exists x \forall y \neg \phi (x,y)$ (making the antecedent false)

OR

> $\exists y \forall x \phi(x,y)$ (making the consequent true).

(17 line proof using: $A\to B \equiv \neg A \lor B$)

Comment: if and only if?

Comment: @Programmer2134 Hint 2: consider the formula $x=y$.

Comment: @AlexKruckman ... in a language with equality.

Comment: @Programmer2134 Hint 3: It does not hold when the domain of discourse is empty.

Comment: @FabioSomenzi In my experience, the modern consensus is that first-order languages have equality by default. Since the OP didn't explicitly say the question is about first-order logic without equality, I'm going to assume they have equality.

Comment: @AlexKruckman they have equality.

Comment: @Programmer2134 See edit for "if and only if."

Answer (score 5):

I don't know if this answers your questions, but it's too long for a comment.

Put all of your of your statements $\phi(x,y)$ in a 2D array (I assumed countable statements, just for convenience):

\begin{array}{c c c c c}
\phi(x_0,y_0) & \phi(x_1,y_0) & \phi(x_2,y_0) & \phi(x_3,y_0) & \dots\\
\phi(x_0,y_1) & \phi(x_1,y_1) & \phi(x_2,y_1) & \phi(x_3,y_1) & \dots \\
\phi(x_0,y_2) & \phi(x_1,y_2) & \phi(x_2,y_2) & \phi(x_3,y_2) & \dots \\
\vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \ddots
\end{array}
then you'll notice that the first statement $\exists x\forall y$ is saying that **a column** in this array is correct. In the second case $\forall y \exists x$ you are simply saying that **each row has at least one correct statement**.

Thus the two are equal either if you only have $1$ column, or if there is at least one column where each row has a correct statement.

Comment: What do you mean? We could extend this to $\exists x \exists y \forall z$ and or other combinations of this kind... then the array would indeed grow in dimension

Comment: I was referring to the kind of statements $\phi$ that would populate such an array.

Comment: You mean each **row** has at least one correct statement.

Comment: @AlexKruckman absolutely. I have corrected it now. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It holds (also) in the case $\phi(x,y)$ is of the form $p(x)\vee q(y)$ or $p(x)\wedge q(y)$. See [Prenex Normal Forms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prenex_normal_form#Conjunction_and_disjunction). For example

\begin{align}
&\exists x\ [\ \forall y\ (\ p(x)\vee q(y)\ )\ ] \\
\iff & \exists x\ [\ p(x)\vee (\ \forall y\ q(y)\ )\ ] \\
\iff & (\ \exists x\  p(x)\ )\vee (\ \forall y\ q(y)\ ) \\
\iff & \forall y\ [\ (\ \exists x\  p(x)\ )\vee  q(y)\ ] \\
\iff & \forall y\ [\ \exists x\  (\ p(x)\vee  q(y)\ )\ ] \\
\end{align}